# Positioning Context Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu

I'm trying to position a custom context menu with jQuery.
The first time it appears at the right position (mouse coordinates), but then the current position is being summed up with the new position, so that the menu disappears from the screen.
Here is the JavaScript:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#box').hide();

    $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
        $("#box").offset({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
        $('#box').show();
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $(document).bind("click", function(e) {
        $('#box').hide();
    });
    $('#box').bind("click", function(e) {
        $('#box').hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: By the way, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on) has supplanted `.bind()` in recent versions of jQuery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Don't use `offset` method, try `css` instead, positioning context menu absolutely:

```
$("#box").css({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
```

CSS:

```
#box {
    ...
    position: absolute;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/smxLk/

Comment: I actually like this better in any case.  Correctly understanding the CSS and setting it accordingly will always be better than using jQuery in my opinion, but I would make one emendation.  I would use `fixed` instead of `absolute`.  this way it can't be affected by a non-static parent and it doesn't cause scrollbars.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Using `position: fixed` makes context menu behave oddly :http://jsfiddle.net/smxLk/1/ on the page with long page content. `position:absolute` works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/smxLk/2/.
I also think that before showing we have to check if menu goes off the screen and fix its position acordingly otherwise menu does not make sense if it's clipped.

Comment: Good points.  I forgot it would stay in one spot when you scroll with `position:fixed`. XD

Comment: It won't work in a proper way when #box container have any margin, or have any other content placed before #box

Answer (score 11):

Try position: fixed; with position of context menu changes based on following condition -

```
var windowHeight = $(window).height()/2;
var windowWidth = $(window).width()/2;
if(e.clientY > windowHeight && e.clientX <= windowWidth) {
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("left", e.clientX);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("bottom", $(window).height()-e.clientY);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("right", "auto");
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("top", "auto");
} else if(e.clientY > windowHeight && e.clientX > windowWidth) {
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("right", $(window).width()-e.clientX);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("bottom", $(window).height()-e.clientY);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("left", "auto");
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("top", "auto");
} else if(e.clientY <= windowHeight && e.clientX <= windowWidth) {
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("left", e.clientX);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("top", e.clientY);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("right", "auto");
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("bottom", "auto");
} else {
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("right", $(window).width()-e.clientX);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("top", e.clientY);
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("left", "auto");
  $("#contextMenuContainer").css("bottom", "auto");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AkshayBandivadekar/zakn7Lwb/14/

Comment: This was I looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that when you right click then left click elsewhere and then right click again, the position is incorrect.

The root of the problem is that you set the offset before showing the element.  It appears that it confuses jQuery if the element is set to `display:none` and then its offset is changed.

To fix the problem you need to switch the `show` and the `offset` lines in your code:

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    $("#box").offset({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    $('#box').show();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

becomes

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
    $('#box').show();
    $("#box").offset({left:e.pageX, top:e.pageY});
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/odulig/2) 
and
[**Source**](http://jsbin.com/odulig/2/edit)

Comment: Is this a bug in jQuery, then?

Comment: @Blazemonger Perhaps.  I'm not sure it would get fixed, however, because it doesn't really make sense to alter the offset of a hidden element.  But I don't have a definitive answer for you, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

i wrote this code using jquery to position my contextmenu

```
$('body').contextmenu(function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let locationX = e.clientX;
    let locationY = e.clientY;
    let ContextWidth = $('#context').width();
    let ContextHeight = $('#context').height();
    let windowWidth = $(window).outerWidth();
    let windowHeight = $(window).outerHeight();

    if (locationY + ContextHeight > windowHeight){
        locationY -= ContextHeight;
    }
    if (locationX + ContextWidth > windowWidth){
        locationX -= ContextWidth;
    };

    $('#context').fadeIn().css({'left': locationX + 'px', 'top': locationY + 'px'});
});
```

if you want to use this you need to write this css #context {position: fixed; left: 0; top: 0; display: none;}