# Positioning element near the clicked area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to integrate a context menu with jQuery full calendar plugin. I couldn't find any example i tried building my own. Its working but not getting proper position. I have tried almost 10 days and googled a lot and couldn't find a solution.

I manually generate HTML for menu item based on event object passed and showing. I have used [Positioning Context Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15795253/positioning-context-menu) solution to position.

How to position context menu properly?

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //all fullCalendar options goes here,
    eventRender: function (event, element, view) {                     
                    element.bind('contextmenu', function (e) {
                        //generate my own <ul><li> html based on event object
                        var contextMenuHtml = getContextMenu(event);
                        //contextMenuContainer is hidden div in at the bottom of <body>
                        $('#contextMenuContainer').html(contextMenuHtml);

                        $('#contextMenuContainer').fadeIn();
                        var position = element.position();

                        $('#contextMenuContainer').css({
                            left: e.pageX, //to show the container close to where i click
                            top: e.pageY // How can i adjust or calculate position if i click near to edge of window
                        });

                        $(document).click(function () {
                            $('#contextMenuContainer').fadeOut();
                        });

                        return false;
                    });
    }
});
```

[image]

I tried to use this [jQuery contextMenu](https://swisnl.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo.html) plugin but which doesnt suite my requirement. I need to dynamically generate menu items with links based on fullCalander event object which I shown above. But unfortunately these plugins not supporting such and no examples like that.

Comment: Have you considered loading JQueryUI? https://jqueryui.com/position/ works well.

Comment: @Malk I already tried assigning `position.top`. Its not positioned closer to where i clicked.. :(

Comment: Nah it doesn't work like that. Check the link. You use it like `$(e).position({my:'left', at:'right', of:event})`.

Comment: @Malk, You saved me!!!. It works like charm `$('#contextMenuContainer').position({
                            my: 'center top',
                            at: 'center bottom',
                            of: evt,
                            offset: '0 5',
                            collision: 'fit'
                        })`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer because under dependencies `jQuery-contextMenu` lists `jQuery UI position` as optional:
https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu#dependencies

You can build a jQueryUI package with just this function here: http://jqueryui.com/download/

Or it looks like the contextMenu has a version in their distribution files: https://github.com/swisnl/jQuery-contextMenu/tree/master/dist

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  //all fullCalendar options goes here,
  eventRender: function (event, element, view) {                     
      element.bind('contextmenu', function (e) {

          var contextMenuHtml = getContextMenu(event);

          $('#contextMenuContainer')
             .html(contextMenuHtml)
             .position({
                 my: 'left-5 top-5',
                 of: e,
                 collision: "fit"
              })
             .fadeIn();


          $(document).click(function () {
              $('#contextMenuContainer').fadeOut();
           });

          return false;
       });
  }
});
```